# LibGit2 clone repo using ssh: Invalid version 0 on git_clone_options

Tags: git, ssh, libgit2

I apologize in advance because I'm extremely new to libgit2/git.  I was trying to clone a git repository using ssh, and I'm getting an error below:

```
Error code: -1 Invalid version 0 on git_clone_options
```

I replaced some paths with arbitrary variables for privacy.  I just believe I'm doing the steps improperly.

```
cred_acquire_cb(git_cred** cred, const char* url, const char* username_from_url, unsigned int allowed_types, void* payload)
{
return git_cred_ssh_key_new(cred, "git", URL, pathToPublicKey, passPhrase);
}

git_repository* repo;
git_remote** remote;
g_options.remote_callbacks.certificate_check;
g_options.remote_callbacks.credentials = cred_acquire_cb;
g_options.remote_cb_payload = pathToCopyTo;
printError(git_clone(&repo, sshURL, pathToCopyTo, &g_options));
```

Answer (score 2):

The various `git_*_options` structures need to be initialized explicitly.  (You cannot have them simply pointing to uninitialized memory.)  You can do so quite easily, either using the handy initializer:

```
git_clone_options options = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
options.remote_callbacks.credentials = cred_acquire_cb;
```

Or you can call a simple function to do it for you:

```
git_clone_options options;
git_clone_init_options(&options, GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_VERSION);
```

Comment: Also works for `git_checkout_options` using `GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT`

Comment: Any insight on how to do this now? It does not appear that `remote_callback.credentials` is a property of the clone options any longer. But maybe I am just not understanding the documentation. https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_clone_options

Comment: @Thenlie they're in the fetch options now -- `options.fetch_opts.remote_callbacks.credentials`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. You are spot on.