# how to disable ssl verification on pygit2

Tags: python, git, libgit2, pygit2

I'm using pygit2 to programmatically clone a repo from an internal server which holds a self-signed certificate.
The pygit2 raises an error on the certificate, how do I turn the verification off?

Comment: please can you post the line(s) of code that try to do this, it will make it easier to answer

Answer (score 0):

That check is done because of [`pygit2/remote.py#L170-L175`](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/blob/456bf59a88b559bdea8af5090b4191842e976e96/pygit2/remote.py#L170-L175)

```
def _fill_fetch_options(self, fetch_opts):
    fetch_opts.callbacks.certificate_check = self._certificate_cb
```

As [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469509/6309), you could override the [callback function with your own](http://www.pygit2.org/remotes.html#pygit2.RemoteCallbacks.certificate_check) (which would do nothing) for the [`git_fetch_options` struct](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/blob/456bf59a88b559bdea8af5090b4191842e976e96/pygit2/decl.h#L233-L240).

```
git_fetch_options options = GIT_FETCH_OPTIONS_VERSION;
options.git_remote_callbacks.certificate_check = my_own_cred_acquire_cb;
```

This approach is echoed and confirmed in the [OP's own issue on pygit2](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/issues/627):

> You can't tell pygit2/libgit2 to ignore everything, but you can provide your own certificate validation function as a callback.
>   If you set `certificate_check` to some function you write, you can ignore the certificate for your known-bad host.

Comment: thank you, i overrode the certificate_check and always returns True but still failed. an error raised with the saying "to many redirects".
https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/issues/627